# jQuery works in JSFiddle but not in local RoR. TypeError?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

The following is my code in "_form.html.erb":

```
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script language='JavaScript'>
      checked = false;
      function checkedAll () {
        if (checked == false){checked = true}else{checked = false}
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('myform').elements.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById('myform').elements[i].checked = checked;
      }
      }
    </script>

    <script language='JavaScript'>
    function checkAnimal() {
    var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
    $("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", true);

    }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <form id="myform">
    Foo1<input type="checkbox" name="foo1"/>
    Bar2<input type="checkbox" name="bar2"/>
    Rah3<input type="checkbox" name="rah3"/>
    Check all: <input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll()'>
    </form>

    <form id='list'><br>
    1<input type='checkbox' value='1' />
    2<input type='checkbox' value='2' />
    3<input type='checkbox' value='3' />
    4<input type='checkbox' value='4' />
    5<input type='checkbox' value='5' />
    CheckAnimal<input type='checkbox' ID="checkAnimalCheckbox" name='checkanimal' onclick='checkAnimal()'><br>
    </form>

   </body>
```

Firebug shows TypeError on my function "checkAnimal()". It says "TypeError: $(...).find is not a function

...("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", true...".

The following is my "checkAnimal()" function code: (Please note that the code works perfectly in JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dUHx3/)

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
function checkAnimal() {
var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
$("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", true);

}
</script>
```

Your input is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you use another JavaScript library that uses `$`? Like MooTools?

Comment: Yes! I have another JavaScript that uses $. And As Rajesh suggested, I changed $ to jQuery and now the code works as expected. Thank you so much! Will accept answer as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: So you didn't put the same code in jsfiddle as in your local environment?

Comment: I think I know what happened! So I had two JavaScripts in my .erb file, but I only tested each code individually in jsfiddle, which passed flawlessly since there was no "$" conflict.. Is this the duplicate of jQuery you're talking about? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from

**this**

```
$("#list").find....
```

**to**

```
jQuery("#list").find...
```

**Reason**

> By default, Rails comes packed with the Prototype javascript library and the effects library, Scriptaculous.

By default, jQuery uses $ as a shortcut for jQuery. Thus, if you are using another JavaScript library that uses the $ variable, you can run into conflicts with jQuery. In order to avoid these conflicts, you need to put jQuery in no-conflict mode immediately after it is loaded onto the page and before you attempt to use jQuery in your page.

REFERENCE

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the reference. I will always remember this lesson! I've spent the past three days digging this website for solution, and finally decided to create an account to ask for help. TOTALLY WORTH IT! Thanks again, Rajesh!

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative as well if you really want to use $ as an alias to jQuery since it makes the code concise and also want to avoid the conflict with other libraries using $.

```
<script>

 jQuery.noConflict(); // 

 jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
   // You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
   $( "div" ).hide(); // $ here will refer to jQuery.
 });


 window.onload = function(){
 var mainDiv = $( "main" ); // here $ will refer to whatever it is in the other library.
 }

</script>
```

for further clarification [Check this](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)